# Is it necessary to close MathLink connection?

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

I use WSTP (formerly known as *MathLink*) program LoopTools (here is the link with executables and source: http://www.feynarts.de/looptools/). To create connection within Mathematica, I use command

```
Install["LoopTools"]
```

Now, as we work, we frequently restart kernel, so all symbolic rules are forgotten by kernel, and we need to run `Install` again.

There is another command, `Uninstall`, which terminates the program. My question is: is it really necessary to close every connection?

I was unaware of any problems you may encounter. But then I suddenly found, that LoopTools processes remain active in process table after restarting kernel. So I did the following experiment:

1. Open Mathematica
2. Run Do[Install["LoopTools"],{10}]
3. Observe 10 processes in system monitor.
4. Quit Mathematica.
5. They are still there.

Is the problem in program I use (LoopTools) or in Mathematica? Or it is documented behavior, and I just should be aware of every connection I've opened?

Version: Mathematica 10.1.0.0 Linux x86 (64-bit)

P.S. I think there should be `wstp` tag (since it is how we call MathLink in 10 version), but I cannot create it with my profile stats.

**Edit:** It seems to be module-specific, e.g. *addtwo* example from documentation terminates itself automatically with kernel.

Comment: It is not necessary to close the connection as long as it doesn't cause you any problems. But the fact that these processes (and their overhead in the *MathLink* library) persist otherwise suggests that you should do it. *MathLink* is not infinitely scalable and will run into problems with a surprisingly small number of processes (unless something changed dramatically for version 10). The process model is client-server. Just because you close the client (*Mathematica*), it doesn't mean the server process should necessarily go away.